# WindowManager can not always draw on top

Tags: android, popup, android-service, android-windowmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

In my app I use a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch incoming calls. So when someone calls and in case that I have the phone number stored in my application's DB, I display a window with the name of the caller.

The problem is that in some devices this window is not displayed if the device's screen is off before the phone rings.(If the screen of the device is on, when the phone rings, the window is displayed).
I also delay the drawing of the window for 3 seconds, but this doesn't seem to work.

To display the window I use the following code, where `mView` is a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView`. This code runs in a `Service`.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            dpToPx(72),
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

mParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

After several failing tries I found it.

I had to replace the flag `TYPE_PHONE`with `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will surely work

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Layout_Flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Layout_Flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Layout_Flag = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
    }
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Layout_Flag,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    try {
        mWindowManager.addView(windowView, params);
```